# SAPUI5: Routing transitions not playing backwards in desktop view, despite correct viewLevel

Tags: sapui5

We have a SplitApp - where we use routing - with a the following views configured as targets:

**Master**

```
"controlAggregation": "masterPages"
"viewLevel": 1
```

**Detail**

```
"controlAggregation": "detailPages"
"viewLevel": 2
```

**LineItem**

```
"controlAggregation": "detailPages"
"viewLevel": 3
```

In mobile view the transition animations are displayed in the right direction. In desktop view the animation from LineItem back to Detail is going forward, when it should be going backward.

We use this code inside the LineItem view to navigate to the Detail view:

```
this.router.navTo("Detail", {}, true);
```

I thought this was handled by the viewLevel, but making changes to the viewLevel makes no difference. Can you help me out here?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, could you please also share your route config, since the order of the targets matters

Comment: Have a look at that example: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.SplitApp/preview Is that what you want?